# VM Policy Assignment: NoComplianceReport

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-policy

I'm looking to Audit VM **Security Compliance** given a policy definition with the chosen compliance "rules".

I currently have a **VM** with **AzureMonitorWindowsAgent** and **AzurePolicyforWindows** extensions installed.

I receive the following error message after assigning a **custom** policy definition derived from a DSC to the **VM**:
[image: VM Policy Page]

**Compliance Details:**
**Reason for non-compliance**
No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition. (Error code:   NoComplianceReport)

Existence condition
**Type**
Microsoft.GuestConfiguration/guestConfigurationAssignments
**Name**
[concat('DSCPackageArtifact$pid', uniqueString(policy().assignmentId, policy().definitionReferenceId))]

---

Possible solutions for this problem would be appreciated.

I previously left it for roughly 45 minutes and the error message changed to another error. However, It has not done this again.

---

Apologies if the names are wrong in the Policy Definition below (I have two that don't work giving the same error. This is the smaller example, I have changed the names to match the content above)  

The Policy Definition (redacted has been added to parts of the definition on purpose to post here):

```
 {
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "DSCPackageArtifact_AuditIfNotExists",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "A few of the DSCs for testing",
    "metadata": {
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "DSC Test NonCompliance Policy",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "description": "DSC Test NonCompliance Policy",
        "metadata": {
          "category": "Guest Configuration",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "requiredProviders": [
            "Microsoft.GuestConfiguration"
          ],
          "guestConfiguration": {
            "name": "DSCPackageTestNonCompliance",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "contentType": "Custom",
            "contentUri": "<redacted content uri with SAS token>",
            "contentHash": "F5C0D40FDDCF1DBBE3C1AEF372D4B590F0D2929A220494BF6341DB8FA99A688B"
          }
        },
        "parameters": {
          "IncludeArcMachines": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
              "displayName": "Include Arc connected machines",
              "description": "By selecting this option, you agree to be charged monthly per Arc connected machine.",
              "portalReview": "true"
            },
            "allowedValues": [
              "true",
              "false"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "false"
          }
        },
        "policyRule": {
          "if": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "anyOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "tags['aks-managed-orchestrator']",
                    "exists": "false"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "tags['aks-managed-poolName']",
                    "exists": "false"
                  },
                  {
                    "anyOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "in": [
                          "esri",
                          "incredibuild",
                          "MicrosoftDynamicsAX",
                          "MicrosoftSharepoint",
                          "MicrosoftVisualStudio",
                          "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
                          "MicrosoftWindowsServerHPCPack"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                            "notLike": "2008*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "MicrosoftSQLServer"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                            "notLike": "SQL2008*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "microsoft-dsvm"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                            "like": "dsvm-win*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "microsoft-ads"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                            "in": [
                              "standard-data-science-vm",
                              "windows-data-science-vm"
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "batch"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                            "equals": "rendering-windows2016"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "center-for-internet-security-inc"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                            "like": "cis-windows-server-201*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "pivotal"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                            "like": "bosh-windows-server*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                            "equals": "cloud-infrastructure-services"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                            "like": "ad*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "anyOf": [
                              {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/osProfile.windowsConfiguration",
                                "exists": true
                              },
                              {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
                                "like": "Windows*"
                              },
                              {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets/osProfile.windowsConfiguration",
                                "exists": true
                              },
                              {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
                                "like": "Windows*"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "anyOf": [
                              {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                                "exists": false
                              },
                              {
                                "allOf": [
                                  {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                                    "notLike": "SQL2008*"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                                    "notLike": "2008*"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "value": "[parameters('IncludeArcMachines')]",
                    "equals": true
                  },
                  {
                    "anyOf": [
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "type",
                            "equals": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/imageOffer",
                            "like": "windows*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "allOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "type",
                            "equals": "Microsoft.ConnectedVMwarevSphere/virtualMachines"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.ConnectedVMwarevSphere/virtualMachines/osProfile.osType",
                            "like": "windows*"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
            "details": {
              "type": "Microsoft.GuestConfiguration/guestConfigurationAssignments",
              "name": "[concat('DSCPackageTestNonCompliance$pid', uniqueString(policy().assignmentId, policy().definitionReferenceId))]",
              "existenceCondition": {
                "field": "Microsoft.GuestConfiguration/guestConfigurationAssignments/complianceStatus",
                "equals": "Compliant"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "name": "6c0551da-e3e9-4d16-9eb4-7e7d914de35c",
      "createdBy": "6f196293-8255-4cf7-88cc-8d7b201802ee",
      "createdOn": "2023-10-12T08:28:43.8359707Z",
      "updatedBy": "6f196293-8255-4cf7-88cc-8d7b201802ee",
      "updatedOn": "2023-10-12T08:31:05.3297191Z"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "IncludeArcMachines": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Include Arc connected machines",
          "description": "By selecting this option, you agree to be charged monthly per Arc connected machine.",
          "portalReview": "true"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "true",
          "false"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "false"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "field": "tags['aks-managed-orchestrator']",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "tags['aks-managed-poolName']",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                    "in": [
                      "esri",
                      "incredibuild",
                      "MicrosoftDynamicsAX",
                      "MicrosoftSharepoint",
                      "MicrosoftVisualStudio",
                      "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
                      "MicrosoftWindowsServerHPCPack"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                        "notLike": "2008*"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "MicrosoftSQLServer"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                        "notLike": "SQL2008*"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "microsoft-dsvm"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                        "like": "dsvm-win*"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "microsoft-ads"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                        "in": [
                          "standard-data-science-vm",
                          "windows-data-science-vm"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "batch"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                        "equals": "rendering-windows2016"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "center-for-internet-security-inc"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                        "like": "cis-windows-server-201*"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "pivotal"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                        "like": "bosh-windows-server*"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                        "equals": "cloud-infrastructure-services"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                        "like": "ad*"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "anyOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/osProfile.windowsConfiguration",
                            "exists": true
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
                            "like": "Windows*"
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets/osProfile.windowsConfiguration",
                            "exists": true
                          },
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
                            "like": "Windows*"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "anyOf": [
                          {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                            "exists": false
                          },
                          {
                            "allOf": [
                              {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                                "notLike": "SQL2008*"
                              },
                              {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                                "notLike": "2008*"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "value": "[parameters('IncludeArcMachines')]",
                "equals": true
              },
              {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/imageOffer",
                        "like": "windows*"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.ConnectedVMwarevSphere/virtualMachines"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.ConnectedVMwarevSphere/virtualMachines/osProfile.osType",
                        "like": "windows*"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.GuestConfiguration/guestConfigurationAssignments",
          "name": "[concat('DSCPackageTestNonCompliance$pid', uniqueString(policy().assignmentId, policy().definitionReferenceId))]",
          "existenceCondition": {
            "field": "Microsoft.GuestConfiguration/guestConfigurationAssignments/complianceStatus",
            "equals": "Compliant"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/<redacted subscription_id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/DSCPackageArtifact_AuditIfNotExists",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "DSCPackageArtifact_AuditIfNotExists",
  "systemData": {
    "createdBy": "<redacted emailaddress>",
    "createdByType": "User",
    "createdAt": "2023-10-12T08:28:43.8134715Z",
    "lastModifiedBy": "<redacted emailaddress>",
    "lastModifiedByType": "User",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2023-10-12T08:31:05.2747104Z"
  }
}
```

---

Update: The Compliance Audit works when using a .mof file on the Desired State Configuration Management tab of the VM. However, this process has been retired for Linux ([DSC Extension for Linux Retired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-linux)). I'm looking for a non-retired solution.

---

Update 2: I have discovered that the method I am taking does not automatically create a GuestAssignment and so it looks like the NoComplianceReport is stating that It cannot find the GuestAssignment. I am trying to create it myself now to test.

Comment: Can you please share the Azure Policy Code, what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, just added.

Comment: Share the exact requirement, what you are looking for..

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for it to audit the security compliance of a VM. A good built-in policy definition example is one of the CIS Benchmark Initiatives

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to Audit VM  **Security Compliance**  given a policy definition with the chosen compliance "rules".
> I currently have a  **VM**  with  **AzureMonitorWindowsAgent**  and **AzurePolicyforWindows**  extensions installed.

To audit the security compliance of `virtual machines` and `virtual machine scale sets` with the required configurations.

```json
 {
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
              "in": [
                "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent",
                "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent",
                "AzurePolicyforWindows",
                "IaaSAntimalware"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags['aks-managed-orchestrator']",
              "exists": false
            },
            {
              "field": "tags['aks-managed-poolName']",
              "exists": false
            },
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                  "in": [
                    "esri",
                    "incredibuild",
                    "MicrosoftDynamicsAX",
                    "MicrosoftSharepoint",
                    "MicrosoftVisualStudio",
                    "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
                    "MicrosoftWindowsServerHPCPack"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "MicrosoftSQLServer"
                    },
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                      "notLike": "SQL2008*"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "microsoft-dsvm"
                    },
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                      "like": "dsvm-win*"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "microsoft-ads"
                    },
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                      "in": [
                        "standard-data-science-vm",
                        "windows-data-science-vm"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "batch"
                    },
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                      "equals": "rendering-windows2016"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "center-for-internet-security-inc"
                    },
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                      "like": "cis-windows-server-201*"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "pivotal"
                    },
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                      "like": "bosh-windows-server*"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                      "equals": "cloud-infrastructure-services"
                    },
                    {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                      "like": "ad*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Once the `policy` is assigned to the required scope, it starts auditing the resources based on conditions, as below.

[image]

Comment: This works for me also. However, I'm trying to pull the security compliance rules from a guest configuration that points to a Configuration Package Artifact stored in blob as a zip file: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/machine-configuration/how-to-create-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Error Message States the following:
**Compliance Details:**
Reason for non-compliance
No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition. (Error code: NoComplianceReport)

**Existence condition**
Type
Microsoft.GuestConfiguration/guestConfigurationAssignments
Name
[concat('DSCPackageArtifact$pid', uniqueString(policy().assignmentId, policy().definitionReferenceId))]

---

It appears that the GuestAssignment has not been automatically created as it should have.
Manually creating a GuestAssignment and changing the GuestAssignment name in the policy definition solves this issue.

[image: PolicyDefinition]

[image: GuestAssignment]

Unfortunately, it is unclear why the GuestAssignment is not automatically created

Answer (score 0):

the main solution I found is never use a dynamic name for your policy guest assignement it should be static one string do not use functions like concat and uniquestring, also some more useful tips to check :

1. Make sure you are using an Managed Identity that have contributor as RBAC and create the remediation task over the resource.
2. Also make sure your blob is publicly accessible for the guest assignement to be able to pull the .mof file.
3. Check the logs in %programdata%/GuestConfig to see if there are any other issues preventing the policy from installing the mof if you are using ApplyAndAutoCorrect.
4. you can force trigger the policy evaluation using az policy trigger scan command to reevaluation or relaunching a remediation.
5. you might need to wait up to 24hours for the policy evaluation.